# Adding values of two stacks of the same size

Tags: c++, stack

I'm just practicing creating a stack class and I'm trying to overload `operator=` and `operator+`. So far I have successfully overloaded the `operator=`.

Let's say my objective is to be able to do `st3 = st1 + st2;` operation in the main where st1, st2, st3 are the objects of class stack and assuming they all have the same size and are all int values.

Right now st3 is not returning any values.

In my class I had:

```
 stack& operator+(stack& otherStack){
        int sum = 0;
        stack res;
        while ((!this->isEmpty()) && (!otherStack.isEmpty())) {
            sum = this->top() + otherStack.top();
            res.push(sum);
            this->pop();
            otherStack.pop();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

And here is my `print()` function using recursion which is also in `class stack`. It prints st1 and st2 just fine

```
void printStack(){
        if (isEmpty())
            return;
        int x = this->top();
        this->pop();
        this->printStack();
        this->push(x);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? I didn't get what is wrong about the code. Overall it seems like a bad idea (operator+) is not really relevant. Swap would be a better candidate. Transforming operations are done using `std::transform` which needs either iterators or views (C++20).

Comment: Do you *really* want the addition of two stacks to empty the stacks? It's a very surprising behaviour. (And printing is simpler to do with a copy, rather than your "modify, recurse, and restore" approach.)

Comment: Well I didn't really have any other way to iterate through the stacks without popping off the top. Again, I'm just testing out all that I can do.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> stack& operator+(stack& otherStack){
>     stack res;
>     ...
>     return res;
> }
> ```

`res` is an automatic variable. Its lifetime ends when it goes out of scope; i.e. when the function returns. You return a reference to this object whose lifetime has ended. The returned reference is always dangling, and attempting to access the object will result in undefined behaviour.

Solution: Return an object; not a reference.

---

Operator+ that modifies the operands is unconventional, and I highly recommend against such design.

Comment: I'm really new at this so I might be wrong but there is no way to return an object in an operand overload function?

Comment: @Jim_Jimmadome Like I said, the solution is to return an object.

Comment: How should I go about doing that? Just a hint is fine

Comment: @Jim_Jimmadome The return type of the function is a reference. To not return a reference, change the return type to not be a reference.

Comment: @Jim_Jimmadome Create a [mcve]